# How do you show the "hg heads" output when you are in TortoiseHG version 2.1.2?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg-2.0

I recently upgraded from TortoiseHG 1.x to TortoiseHG 2.x, and the UI of Tortoise HG is massively changed.

I still have not found any radio button like this in tortoisehg 2.x, to show the heads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

View - Filter toolbar (Ctrl+S) will give you such ability
[image]

Comment: So this replaces the radio buttons from the older tortoisehg 1.x UI, I guess.  I award zero points to the TortoiseHg UI design team for this decision, but I thank them from the bottom of my heart for building this product in the first place. :-)

Comment: Incidentally, I can now see why they dropped the radio buttons. The well hidden ellipsis button visible to the right of the area where you would type in head() brings up an expression builder dialog box where you can find all kinds of expressions, from file name search, to searching by tag or revision or any other kind of metadata, etc.

Comment: weird isn't it?  the tortoisehg sources are clear and easily readable Python code.   I am thinking of writing my own branch of it.  Most bits of TortoiseHG are awesome, but the way that the filtering works is just bizarre to me.